# putting tags onto block quotes after being pulled out of post

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have the following code which pulls the block-quotes out of my Wordpress post and puts it on the page.

HTML

```
<?php
        // get the content
        $block = get_the_content();

        // check and retrieve blockquote
        if(preg_match('~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~', $block, $matches))

        // output blockquote
        echo $matches[1];
    ?>
```

However this doesn't wrap it in the blockqoute tags or < p > tags or anything. I want to apply custom CSS to these actions. What do I have to add to the code to wrap it in a tag?

Comment: `echo '<p>'.$matches[1].'</p>';`

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace` with a capture group:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
$block='bla bla <blockquote> foo bar </blockquote> bla';
echo preg_replace("~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~","<p>$1</p>",$block);
//bla bla <p> foo bar </p> bla
```

Comment: does that code put just the block quote in some kinda tag? My code pulls it out of the wp-admin posts panel, and puts it in posts, I don't have to write nw ones (every post has a unique block quote)